# After the game starts, does healing a hero that damaged themself charge Mercy's ultimate?

Tags: overwatch

Certain characters can damage themselves during the pre-game countdown, notably Junkrat and Pharah. If Mercy heals that damage before the game starts, she doesn't gain ultimate charge (so I've heard). However, does that hold true if she waits for the game to start before healing? Can you just have a Pharah and a Mercy in a corner taking an explosion bath and building ult?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, as seen here in the [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Caduceus_Staff#Details),

> Mercy will build ultimate charge from both healing and damage boosting, but not if the damage is self-inflicted in either case.

Therefore, healing or damage boosting with the Caduceus Staff (which only works on others) does not generate ultimate charge if the damage is self-inflicted (i.e. Mercy would not get ultimate charge by buffing or healing a Junkrat that is standing on bombs as they explode).

Also, as to your comment about ultimate charging in pre-game, this is because ultimate meters don't start charging till the game starts. I've also tested both of these myself.

Comment: I thought that meant that she wouldn't get ultimate points for healing someone *else* who had damaged themselves. I wouldn't think she would get any ultimate points for regenerating her own health, regardless of where the damage came from.

Comment: @DCShannon It is stating that healing or damage boosting with the Caduceus Staff (which only works on others) does not generate ultimate charge if the damage is self-inflicted (i.e. Mercy would get ultimate charge by buffing or healing a Junkrat that is standing on bombs as they explode).

Comment: After reading the question twice more, I think I misunderstood what they were asking. In the title "self-damage" doesn't mean "damage that Mercy inflicted on herself", but is intended to mean "damage that others inflicted on themselves".

Comment: @DCShannon that is what I read it to be asking as well, and is the question I have addressed in my answer. I shall try to make that a little more apparent.

Comment: **NOTE:** my first comment is missing the word "not" in the middle of the example I provided.

Comment: Will health that Mercy restores before the round starts count towards her healing stat for that game? I might want to make this into another question...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf sounds like a great different question. I would say most likely not, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No stats are tracked before the round starts. This includes Symmetra shields cast during the setup. For maximum effect, she would want to shield people as the enemy gates open.